# Algebraic condition that distinguishes embedded from immersed lie subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, and $K$ a subalgebra of $L$. Then, by Lie's correspondence theorems, there exists a unique (up to isomorphisms) simply connected Lie group $G$ having $L$ as a Lie algebra. There also exists a unique connected Lie subgroup $H$ of $G$  having $K$ as its Lie algebra.

Question: What algebraic condition on the pair $(L, K)$ determines if $H$ will be an embedded submanifold or not?

Comment: As you can see from Igor's answer, you are asking whether the connected subgroup generated by K is closed, but I'm afraid that there is no known (to me, but I've asked) purely algebraic condition on (L,K) which will guarantee this; although there are some known sufficient conditions (also listed in Igor's answer.)

Comment: Thank you all for the answers and useful comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [closed-subgroup theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Closed-subgroup_theorem), in particular the [conditions for being closed](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Closed-subgroup_theorem#Conditions_for_being_closed).

Comment: Also, a [further list](//books.google.com/books?id=a9KFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA152) of 8 sufficient conditions for being closed in Helgason (1978).